# Does DISABLE_WP_CRON prevent plugins from registering new cron tasks?

Tags: wp-cron, wp-cli, cron

If I set `DISABLE_WP_CRON` to `true` in my `wp-config.php` file, then will it block plugins from registering new cron events (eg with calls to [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/))

```
define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );
```

I've added the above line to my `wp-config.php`. I think the general assumption is that `DISABLE_WP_CRON` doesn't *actually* block your cron jobs from running (and block plugins from registering new events), but that it just prevents wordpress itself from *initiating* your crons when a visitor loads your website in their web browser.

And, instead, you can just set `DISABLE_WP_CRON` to `true` and then execute your cron jobs outside of the web server (eg with [`wp-cli`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/cron/) and the actual, system cron).

Is this assumption valid? Or does `DISABLE_WP_CRON` actually block crons from running, and block plugins from registering new cron events?

I ask because I'm writing a plugin that tries to register a new cron event with `wp_schedule_event()`. The function returns True, but the new cron job does *not* appear in my event list, so I don't think it will ever be executed by my system's cron.

```
wp cron event list
```

How can I prevent wordpress from executing its own cron via the webserver when my visitors load the website through their web browsers, but still permit [a] crons to be executed by tools like `wp-cli` and [b] plugins to register new cron events?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this assumption valid? Or does DISABLE_WP_CRON actually block crons from running, and block plugins from registering new cron events?

Yes, setting `DISABLE_WP_CRON` to `true` doesn't *actually* block Wordpress' crons from running; it just prevents wordpress itself from initiating the events to run when your backend is triggered by a customer viewing your website.

> I'm writing a plugin that tries to register a new cron event with `wp_schedule_event()`. The function returns True, but the new cron job does not appear in my event list, so I don't think it will ever be executed by my system's cron.

`wp cron event list` will *not* list all of your crons if you're using wordpress multisite.

I don't know of a built-in way to get `wp-cli` to just dump all of the crons for all of your sites, but here's a simple bash loop that will iterate through each of your sites and list all scheduled cron events for each site.

```
urls=$(wp site list --field=url)
for url in $urls; do
    echo ${url}
    sudo cron --url=${url} event list
    echo
done
```